# Some Teamcity agent hosts do not have access to git master branch

Tags: git, teamcity

We have the following setup for TeamCity (Version 2017.2.3 (build 51047)):

VCS is git.

**VCS Root Settings**

Default branch:

```
refs/heads/develop
```

Branch Specification :

```
+:refs/heads/(develop)
+:refs/heads/(master)
```

The build is triggered whenever there is a commit to the 'develop' branch.

We have a command-line build step which runs a bash script.
In the bash script, I try to find the merge base of the develop branch with the master branch via the following commands:

```
branchName=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
git merge-base $branchName master
```

We see that there are certain agent hosts on which we get an error:

**[Step 4/4] fatal: Not a valid object name master**

This happens when that particular agent host does not seem to have all the git branches.
**Is there a specific agent property/setting that we need to enable that will ensure that any agent host will always have access to both the master and develop branches?**

Comment: Wouldn't the "Automatic merge" build feature be more appropriate in this case? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Automatic+Merge Or the bash script contains more logic that requires you to execute this step using this script?